Not able to add loop cuts
I'm not able to add loop cuts in this current mesh. what I initially did was make each face myself manually maybe thats the issue because of which loop cuts aren't working correctly.
I have no idea as new to blender.

that's because your topology is terrible. For one it's way too complicated and also it doesn't form closed loops. You can create a a loop cut only in between already existing loops so that blender knows the flow of topology

@JiříHonzák so should I remake this entirely or is there any other way?

@SrijanGupta try using the knife tool (K button)

@Lynx095 yes this definitely helped to solve it. thanks.

loopcuts can only be created through quads, if the face is a tri or a ngon, the operation won't work, that said you can use the knife to create a new edge loop

Honestly, seeing how unnecessarily complex the topology is I'd recommend to watch a few vids on how to create clean topo and try it again. If you use knife tool you can create loops but it won't repair the topology, it'll just move the problem into other part of the model. The model itself seems like it could be created pretty low poly with subD applied. Ofc depends on what you need but if you are a beginner modeler I think you should take the time and learn to create topo properly. It'll save you a tone of work later when texturing etc.
